# byteArray response from server is not complete at clientside

Tags: javascript

Backend service sends byteArray and its length is more than 40 thousand records, however, "responseArray" in the below code shows 13 records. How can I get all records at client side?

```
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        var responseArray = new Uint8Array(this.response);
                    }
                }
    xhr.open('POST', '/Docs/GetByteArray');
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhr.send("docId="+docId+"&docName="+docInfo.Name+"&documentType="+docInfo.DocumentType+"&options="+optionsXmlStr );
```

service method...

public byte[] GetByteArray(POC.Controllers.Request docData) 
{var response = cService.process(request); byte[] docBytes = new byte[0]; if (response.Payload != null) docBytes = response.Payload.Document; return docBytes
}

Comment: what does server side code look like?

Comment: What does the network traffic look like? Does the HTTP response hold multiple kilobtyes of data?

Comment: Even if service sends 5 records, it it shows 13 records in XHR response.  byte[] docBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };  return docBytes;